# SCDF accepts registration of new application, but does not create it

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We've got into a strange situation. SCDF, through both UI and REST, accepts requests for creation of new applications (and changes of their default versions). We get confirmation messages in UI and 201, 202 responses from REST calls.

However, no changes appear in the list of applications. Logs of the SCDF server are empty about acceptance of the request and error to create the applications.

The updates do appear in "app_registration" table and they can be retrieved using "/apps" REST endpoint. The problem seems in UI.

Version: 2.3.0.RELEASE

How would you debug this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is true with UI and it's already in new versions of SCDF
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues/1381

When the number of registered versions of applications exceeds 1000 UI starts having troubles. Strange that even on the page with details of a particular application UI fails to show, let's say, all 4 versions if the fourth one happened to be 1001st in the app_registration table

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions.

You could review the database directly. Specifically, look at the `app_registration` table. Check whether the records that you attempted to insert via the UI or REST show up correctly.

Also, verify the results by hitting the [`/apps`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#resources-app-registry-list) endpoint.

It could be that the API that you're pointing to is running against a different SCDF instance of a database.

It might also be possible that the SCDF database is pointing to in-memory storage, and that you may have restarted SCDF. When that happens, the in-memory footprint is wiped-off anyway. That's why a persistent RDBMS storage is recommended.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions. Today I checked the database (SQL Server) and found the applications, which I tried to register yesterday, there. However, today they also appear in UI and new registrations succeed too. Hence I'm a bit puzzled and not much can be done now

Comment: The problem is reproducible again. I extended the question with
```
The updates do appear in "app_registration" table and they can be retrieved using "/apps" REST endpoint. The problem seems in UI.
```